# Ruby Regexp Match String Exactly

Tags: ruby, regex

From:

```
14291@;@yfsun@;@some@string; .NET@;@200
```

To:

```
id=14291  name=yfsun  msg=some@string; .NET  code=200
```

My regex is :

```
/^(?<id>[^@]*)@;@(?<name>[^@]*)@;@(?<msg>[^@]*)@;@(?<code>[^@]*)$/
```

As you can see, `msg` part would be a problem because `msg` may has `@` string.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: I don't see, please explain what it is you want or expect and what you need in detail.

Comment: Just change the `msg` named group to be greedy. `(?<msg>.*)`

Comment: @hwnd nice, that's what I want, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `<code>` is the last named group, you can simply change `<msg>` to be [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#greedy).

```
(?<msg>.*)
```

[**Rubular**](http://rubular.com/r/msYQREBEEi)

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why a simple regex won't do. Am I overlooking something?

```
str = "14291@;@yfsun@;@some@string; .NET@;@200"

id, name, msg, code = str.split(/@;@/)
id = id.to_i     #=> 14291 
name             #=> "yfsun" 
msg              #=> "some@string; .NET" 
code = code.to_i #=> 200
```

Comment: Simple, this would be more efficient (`+1`)

Comment: I need to use regex to do this because this is app's config, support regex only, so can not use split function...

Comment: But `split`'s argument is a regex (though it could have been a string). You have to  use some method (probably `scan` or `split`) in conjunction with the regex. You can't use a regex by itself for anything.

Comment: Actually I'm using fluentd. I can show you here: http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail . If you search `regexp` on this page, you can find the `format` option, should be regexp.

Comment: I tried `/(?<test>.+?)(?=@;@|$)/` at fluentd's parser. It parsed but I don't know if it would work in the subsequent step. (Just a stab in the dark.)